# ShowShareSheet creates black/blank screen

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe4

Using DELPHI XE4/XE5.

[image]

Using an ActionList and Tbutton that is linked to the aciton: ActionShowShareSheet, the picture above is my result. I can not find a lot of troubleshooting around or many examples regarding the topic. I am trying to share an image with informational text - nothing to fancy - either by email or whichever the desired social sharing service is preferred by the user.

Yes, I have looked at the example provided by Delphi, and even attempted copying and pasting the same controls/components from that example.

edit ---

Okay, so I tested in in the iPad as well, it appears to show the popver modal but no items are shown to share with. So I am now facing two problems:
1. ShowActionShareSheet does not display properly with an iPhone device/simulator
2. I have nothing to share with, or I can't. I have signed into Facebook as a test via the iOS device settings and it still does not work properly.

Help ! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

~ Simple solution. Just doesn't work in the simulator.